# Saving dates in a matrix ("origin must be supplied") with r

Tags: r, date, datetime, strptime

I am writing my bachelor thesis and I have not much experience with r so far.
My problem is that my dates which I made with this commands :

```
t<-strptime(x, "%d.%m.%Y %H.%M")
```

don't work anymore when I save them in a matrix with the other information on those specific dates.

I am a bit confused because it works just fine when I don't put them in a matrix like this    `t[1:10]`

But that happens as soon as I try to save them in a matrix

```
matrix1<-matrix(c(t,v2,v3,v4),nrow=length(v2))

Fehler in as.POSIXct.numeric(X[[i]], ...) : 'origin' muss angegeben werden
```

It's German but it means origin must be supplied.

Any ideas what I have to do to fix it? I am a bit frustrated :)

Answer (score 0):

`t` (terrible name by the way, easily confused with the `t` function) is a POSIXlt object, which internally is a list. First you should check, what `c(t,v2,v3,v4)` returns (I don't know how `v2` etc are defined).

Then we can look into the documentation in `help("matrix")`:

> data
>   an optional data vector (including a list or expression vector). Non-atomic classed R objects are coerced by as.vector and all attributes discarded.

The important bit is "all attributes discarded". This is what you get if you discard the attributes (which include the class attribute) of a POSIXlt object:

```
x <- strptime(c("2016-05-09 12:00:00", "2016-05-09 13:00:00"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
attributes(x) <- NULL
print(x)
# [[1]]
# [1] 0 0
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 0 0
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 12 13
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 9 9
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 4 4
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 116 116
# 
# [[7]]
# [1] 1 1
# 
# [[8]]
# [1] 129 129
# 
# [[9]]
# [1] 1 1
# 
# [[10]]
# [1] "CEST" "CEST"
# 
# [[11]]
# [1] NA NA
```

A matrix can't contain POSIXlt objects (or any objects, i.e., anything with an explicit class).

Comment: ok but do you have any idea how i put those dates together with my vektors v1 (average windspeed), v2 "density) v3 (max windspeed) v4 (min windspeed)

Comment: because my main problem is that I have a data set with some gaps in between and I try to find a solid way to get a proper set of data.

Comment: You probably want a data.frame instead of a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Roland is right. You can't have Posixlt objects in a matrix. What you can do is save those dates as numeric timestamps in the matrix and convert them back to dates while accessing
Converting to numeric timestamp:

```
>date<- as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2014-02-16 2:13:46 UTC",origin="01-01-1970"))
>date
[1] 1392545626
```

Then save those timestamps in a matrix as you do and to convert it back to date, use the above command again without converting it into a numeric.